# Twilio message sent to Mexico with different number from the one bought on twillio

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm using twillio for sending sms from a rails app.

Integration was very easy, but I found a problem. When i send a message the recipient receive an sms with a different number from the one I have configured on the twillio web interface.

In my case the recipients automatically reply to my message and I need that they reply to the twillio numbers in order to process the texts.

Twillio numbers is US based while the recipient's number are from mexico.

Comment: Hey Kerby, I'd report this to Twilio support on help@twilio.com and hopefully this can be resolved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: In some cases – and Mexico is one of this – due to some limitation from the provider of the country the Sender ID is translated to a local number. The only solution to this was to use a local Mexican Number and to do so I had to request for the Beta global numbers since Mexico numbers are not yet completely open.

Answer (score 0):

While not completely an answer to your issue with Twilio I can add some insights. Sending SMS's via international numbers so non Mexican mobile subscriber numbers is inherently tricky. This is the case for most South America countries unfortunately.

They tend to limit who can route SMS's into the country a lot more than other countries. Therefore a lot of SMS gateway providers like Twilio instead arrange with local SMS gateways to route SMS traffic into countries like Mexico. Therefore explaining why your recipients are receiving SMS from a different originator number.

As a side note I know of a couple of international players that also operate within South America which don't have this issue. They are pretty easy to Google up :)